# Retrieving the last user message from chat - inbox

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm building a chat section of my website and here is what I came up with for the query for retrieving last message for inbox and the conversation.

```
     $chat_inbox = Message::where('author_id', $this->user->id)
        ->orWhere('recipient_id', $this->user->id)
        ->groupBy('unique_chat_id')
        ->latest();
```

the problem is that I need to find the last message that the other user sent, not the one sending the message. I can then display this message as unread in the inbox, but I also need to retrieve the conversation that the current user started even if the other use still have not responded.

This current query will get me the last message no matter who sent it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You current query is saying: "Get me the latest message that <this user> either sent or received for <this chat room>". Based on your question, I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that its not a 100%. But, I have read a tonn of stackoverflow threads and looked at a shitload of online resources and I cant figure out how to go about getting my chat inbox together

Answer (score 0):

You must change the statement of `where`.

```
$chat_inbox = Message::where('recipient_id', $this->user->id)
    ->where('chat_id', some_id')
    ->groupBy('unique_chat_id')
    ->last();
```

Comment: sry use `->latest()` instead of `->last()`